# id gets undefined on click event

Tags: angularjs, django

I am getting value in details and it also have id in it. But while fetching it shows Id is Undefined

html

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in details" ng-include="getTemplate(detail)">


            </tr>    

            <script type="text/ng-template" id='display'>

              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="delete(detail.id)">delete</button></td>

                </script>
```

angular

$scope.delete= function(id)
        {

```
    console.log(id);
    }
        });
```

Comment: you are passing id in delete function, but logging $scope.id,
I thing `ng-click="delete(detail.id)"` from this -> $scope.detail object will bind.

Comment: sorry i edit the questions

Comment: How detail object is bind with $scope?

Comment: sorry i cant get your question.
I am new to this

Comment: <script type="text/ng-template" id='display'>
td>
     {% verbatim %}{{detail.name}}{% endverbatim %}</td>
     <td>
     {% verbatim %}{{detail.address}}{% endverbatim %}</td>
     <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="showedit(detail)">edit</button>

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-ng-click="delete(detail.id)">delete</button></td>

  </script>

Comment: So if you are binding any variable on html page, then it should bind in $scope variable as well. Please go through the link:
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp